# MySQL select last day of month exsist in table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I'm trying to get data from mysql where the date are at the end of month.
Example:

```
id date       name
===================
1  2002-02-23 aaaa
2  2002-02-23 bbbb
3  2002-03-01 cccc
```

As you can see the last input on february are only at date 23 because of various reason.
Is there a way so that i can only select the last date of month **existed** in database?

Comment: so if thats the case, what are the result based on your given records?

Answer (score 3):

@Morgan try this way i think it will give you exact results.

`SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date in 
(select DISTINCT max(date) from table 
GROUP BY MONTH(date ))`

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date in (select max(date) from my_table)
```

it will show the maximum date...in your words date are at the end of month.You can add "GROUPBy" for better result

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6612a/1)

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(date)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take `self join` on table using `derived table` by grouping records with `year-month`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_name a
     INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(`date`) AS `date`
            FROM table_name
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m')
           ) b
        ON a.`date` = b.`date`;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b46c/5)

Query to get only last dates of month:

```
SELECT MAX(`date`) AS `date`
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that works fine in my case

```
SELECT * FROM ProjectTimeSheet WHERE EndDate in (select DISTINCT max(EndDate) from 
ProjectTimeSheet GROUP BY MONTH(EndDate ))
```

Where my table is "ProjectTimeSheet" that has a field named EndDate. And this query retrieves exactly the way you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can select last month dates from your table with this query:

```
select max(`Date`) from t group by DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%Y%m')
```